# Link is not working on logo

Tags: html, css, wordpress

If you look at the logo in the upper left corner on [my site](https://mimsi.dk/), the logo is not clickable. The same thing counts for the basket in the right side. I do not understand why, the code should be fine. Is there something laying over the `div` tag?

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <div id="logo">
        <a href="https://mimsi.dk/">
            <img class="logo-trans logo-reg" src="https://mimsi.dk/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/logo-temp-hvid-132x40.png" height="40" width="132" alt="Logo">
            <img class="logo-main logo-reg" src="https://mimsi.dk/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/logo-temp-hvid-132x40.png" height="40" width="132" alt="Logo">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You haven't provided the css part. Please provide the complete code.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? Could you provide a working code example?

Comment: Thank you for the answers. It is a wordpress site, so I do not have so much control over the CSS. I mostly use the inspect window.

Comment: now such question are getting upvoted ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif. Why dont you use time to participate in the society and my question, instead of using time on a comment like that?

Comment: @MadsKristensen, from my view of point, it's got to do with the elements overblocking it: http://prntscr.com/ij4m0x http://prntscr.com/ij4m9r

Comment: because you should provide us with code and not simply give a link and say "it's not working, can someone go to the website check what is happening and come back to me?"

Comment: @TemaniAfif: Come to Denmark. I will invite you for a cop of coffee and a cake. Then we can take a talk about your frustrations regarding my question. you can catch me on this e-mail adress: mads-pri-DK@gmail.com. Let me know when you arrive in the airport of Copenhagen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add style in your active theme style.css and adjust your menu style .

Menu is overlaping on logo.

```
#wp-megamenu-primary_navigation{
        clear: both;
}
```

or

```
#wp-megamenu-primary_navigation {   
    padding-right: 15px !important;
    padding-left: 15px !important;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. If I add that it is working, but the menu is jumping down to the next line. How can that be?

Comment: Cool thanks that is doing the job. What I worry a little bit about is, that I can see on Ipad size the menu is jumping down again. So I should set that in a media query?

Comment: Yes . you should set that in a media query

Comment: @Downvoter, why Im got downvote for accepted answer?

Comment: no worries i up-voted both of you.  Both can be correct

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `z-index` of the logo and navbar on your site. Make sure you add `position: relative` to ensure that `z-index` works properly.

This moves the logo to the front:

```
.navbar-header {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

And this moves the navbar behind it:

```
.navbar-collapse {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice that did the job with the logo. How can I do the same with the basket in the right side?

Comment: You could set the `z-index` of the basket to `2`.